# How to play a sound file at maximum volume in iOS without a sound indicator change

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, volume, max

In my app I'm required to play a sound from a volume of 0 to maximum system volume (it's     an alarm app).

I currently use `AVAudioPlayer` to play the sound and `MPMusicPlayerController` to maximize the device's volume for the duration of the alarm

```
MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer.volume = 1.0;


NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:alarm.sound];
fileName = [fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension];

NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"aifc"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
audioPlayer.volume = 0.0;
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

audioPlayer.play;
```

and then I schedule a timer to increase the volume

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(pollTimeForGradualVolumeIncrease)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

//Increase the volume gradually

```
- (void)pollTimeForGradualVolumeIncrease
{
    timerSecond += 1;

    if (audioPlayer.volume < 1.0 && timerSecond % 1 == 0)
    {
        [audioPlayer setVolume:audioPlayer.volume + 0.02];
        UISlider *slider = volumeSliderView.subviews[0];
        [slider setValue:1.0 animated:NO];
    }
    else if (audioPlayer.volume >= 1.0)
    {
        timerSecond = 0;
        timer.invalidate;
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the iOS volume indicator will appear when setting `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer.volume`

Is there a way to play a sound file at maximum device volume without the displaying the iOS volume changed indicator?

Comment: You said you are using application musicplayer volume, but i see you are using audioPlayer setVolume which is an AVAudioPlayer, can you clarify?

Comment: From what I understand. ApplicationMusicPlayer sets the master volume for iOS and I use AVAudioPlayer to play the sound. Is this not correct?

I followed the example from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279233/ios-maximum-volume-level-for-avaudioplayer?rq=1.

AVAudioPlayer plays the sound and gradually increase the volume by a fraction of the master volume.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, what you can do is to set the volume to maximum, retain the value of the volume before the change and return to it's original value when you stop playing the sound ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was experimenting with related things 8 months ago, and as far as I remember, if an MPVolumeView is present, iOS then doesn't show the system volume changed indicator.

If you don't actually want to see the MPVolumeView, I suppose you could hide it behind another view.

Comment: I ended up fixing it with a similar solution. I just set MPVolumeView's origin off screen